# Ternary operator in -for- statement

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to use a ternary operator in the last part of the for statement to increase or decrease my index..but it seems not to be a correct statement in c sharp? I am trying to move some code from Javascript thats why im trying this.

```
  for (int _j = 0, _ref = (int) Math.Floor((double)array.Count / 2);
       0 <= _ref ? _j < _ref : _j > _ref; 
       0 <= _ref ? _j++ : _j--)
  { 
      _results1.Add(_j); 
  }
```

Any idea on how to implement the ternary operator in a for statement in C#?

Comment: Just extract the logic out to a method; don't try to inline it.

Comment: That nested ternary makes my eyes bleed :(

Comment: Readable code is so much better though..

Comment: Why would people downvote this?..seriously.

Comment: The ternary is useless, because `array.Count` is never negative.  Just work out which branch is taken and delete the other.

Comment: I down vote because the code is not readable, if I see code like this I will start cursing !

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is "not useful" because you *shouldn't ever do that*. You are sitting at +1/-2, its not that bad.

Comment: it might be horrible, it is not my code, dont know how am i responsible.. i am moving a library from javascript into c sharp.

Comment: @MaG3Stican Using good variable names in public code makes it easier to read and much less likely to attract downvotes. You could have improved your original code and than copy/paste it to question. Also a lot of `_` does not make it better and give no additional information to SO readers (maybe it is your coding guidelines, but commonly C# does not use prefixes for local variables and in most guidelines for members too).

Answer (score 1):

in C# a for statement expects an init-statement, a bool experssion, an increment-statement

You could split this in two cases:

```
_ref = (int) Math.Floor((double)array.Count / 2); // assuming this can go negative...
if(0 <= _ref)
{
    for (int _j = 0; _j < _ref; _j++)
    { 
        _results1.Add(_j); 
    }
}
else
{
    for (int _j = 0; _j > _ref; _j--)
    { 
        _results1.Add(_j); 
    }
}
```

if you like it shorter you may delete all curly braces...

Comment: in the second loop I think you mean `int _j = _ref`

Comment: No, its `_j=0` in both cases.

Comment: And then you can notice that the `if` condition is always true, unless someone invented arrays with negative length when I wasn't looking.

Comment: @BenVoigt `array` is not actually an array.  Arrays don't have a `Count` property.  Not knowing what it is, it could be some type that has a `Count` member that returns negative values.

Comment: Also, a divide-by-two went missing somewhere.  I do believe that `(int)Math.Floor((double) array.Count / 2.0)` is the same as `array.Count >> 1` anyway.

Comment: @Servy: If true, then the variable name is the first thing that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Found the divide and brought it back home. Do not assume .Count to be a positive integer...

Comment: Unlike `array.Count / 2` (integer divide) which truncates toward zero, `array.Count >> 1` should be equivalent to this expression for both positive and negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expression, `0 <= _ref ? _j++ : _j--`, is not a valid statement.  You could make a statement out of it in any number of ways, but as it is its incomplete.  As the error message you get indicates, you need the statement to be an `await`, method call, increment/decrement, or new object expression for it to be a valid expression statement.  The conditional operator isn't on that list.

Of course, rather than adding in an entirely superfluous method call to that expression the real fix is to simply not use the conditional operator like this in the first place, rather than adding even more unreadable code to get it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator expects two expressions, so this won't work. What you can do is:

```
_j += (0 <= _ref ? 1 : -1);
```

That looks worse than terrible, though.

Comment: He provided two expressions.  His code is a valid conditional expression.  `_j++` is an expression.

Comment: @Servy In C#, this won't even compile. `for (var i = 0; i < 10; someBool ? i++ : i--) { }` Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're correct that it won't compile, you're wrong about the *reason* it won't compile.  It errors for an entirely different reason that you stated.  The syntax provided for a conditional operator is perfectly fine; the code doesn't compile because a valid conditional operator is not valid in the context it is used in.